# Feature detector and descriptor for low resolution images

Tags: image, opencv, feature-detection, feature-extraction, feature-tracking

I am working with low resolution (VGA) and jpg-compressed sequences of images for visual navigation on a mobile robot. At the moment I am using SURF for detecting keypoints and extracting descriptors out of the images, and FLANN for tracking them. I am getting 4000-5000 features per image, and usually 350-450 matches are made per pair of consecutive images, before applying RANSAC (which usually reduces 20% the number of matches)

I am trying to increase the number (and quality) of the matches. I have tried two other detectors: SIFT and ORB. SIFT increases the number of features noticeably (35% more of tracked features, overall), but it is much slower. ORB extracts roughly as many features as SURF, but the matching performance is much poorer (~100 matches, in the best cases). My implementation in opencv of ORB is:

```
cv::ORB orb = cv::ORB(10000, 1.2f, 8, 31);
orb(frame->img, cv::Mat(), im_keypoints, frame->descriptors);
frame->descriptors.convertTo(frame->descriptors, CV_32F); //so that is the same type as m_dists
```

And then, when matching:

```
cv::Mat m_indices(descriptors1.rows, 2, CV_32S);
cv::Mat m_dists(descriptors1.rows, 2, CV_32F);
cv::flann::Index flann_index(descriptors2, cv::flann::KDTreeIndexParams(6));
flann_index.knnSearch(descriptors1, m_indices, m_dists, 2, cv::flann::SearchParams(64) );
```

What is the best feature detector and extractor when working with low resolution and noisy images? Should I change any parameter in FLANN depending on the feature detector used?

**EDIT:**

I post some pictures of a fairly easy sequence to track. The pictures are as I give them to the feature detector methods. They have been preprocessed to eliminate some noise (by means of  `cv::bilateralFilter()`)

[image]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: Can you upload some example images? Also, is there much rotation from frame to frame?

Comment: I posted two links to my images. When I uploaded them I realised that I was working with grey-scale images, so I have fixed it in my code and edited my question accordingly. In this sequence there is no rotation at all, although I may get up to 20 degrees of rotation around the vertical axis.

Comment: OK, BRIEF is more accurate than the other binary descriptors in situations with no rotation. I would try it instead of orb.

Comment: Ok. BRIEF for descriptor extractor. And, for the keypoint detector... SURF? or FAST?

Comment: I'm not sure which detector. I would use SIFT if it doesn't need to run fast.

Answer (score 2):

In many cases the [Pyramidal Lucas Kanade](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=pyramidal%20lucas%20kanade#calcopticalflowpyrlk) optical flow based method is a good choice. the method has some restrictions e.g. big changes in illuminations. If you use a large window 21x21 or bigger than the tracker should be more robust to noise. You can get features to track from your favorit SIFT,SURF,FAST or GFT feature detector or you initialise them as a regular sampled grid. That gives you the advantage of  regular samples motion information from your scene.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working with the ORB feature detection for a few months now.
I have found no issue with ORB itself although the authors speak of fine-tuning some of the parameters to make it perform better.

h t t p s://github.com/wher0001/Image-Capture-and-Processing

When I run ORB using your pictures and the standard distance sorting, I get the following picture which obviously has a few bad matches.
[ORB Matching - standard sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rhqW.jpg)

I always set the number of nfeatures high (5000) and start from there.
***It defaults to 500 which is what I used for these pictures.***
From there you can either change how it sorts as I showed here, can reduce the nfeatures number or even just use that top X number of matches.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img1 = cv2.imread("c:/Users/rwheatley/Desktop/pS8zi.jpg")
img2 = cv2.imread("c:/Users/rwheatley/Desktop/vertrk.jpg")

grey1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grey2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Initiate ORB detector
orb = cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=5000)

# find the keypoints and descriptors with ORB
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(grey1,None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(grey2,None)

# create BFMatcher object
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)

# Match descriptors.
matches = bf.match(des1,des2)

# Sort them in the order of their distance.
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)

# Draw first 10 matches.
img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches,None,flags=2)
print(len(matches))

plt.imshow(img3),plt.show()
```

I then switch to a few different methods that I found beneficial when using a (excuse the term) crappy Dell Webcam.
[ORB with knnMatching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMgwQ.jpg)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img1 = cv2.imread("c:/Users/rwheatley/Desktop/pS8zi.jpg")
img2 = cv2.imread("c:/Users/rwheatley/Desktop/vertrk.jpg")

grey1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grey2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Initiate ORB detector
orb = cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=5000)

# find the keypoints and descriptors with ORB
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(grey1,None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(grey2,None)

# BFMatcher with default params
bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(des1,des2, k=2)

# Apply ratio test
good = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.75*n.distance:
        good.append([m])

# cv2.drawMatchesKnn expects list of lists as matches.
img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good,None,flags=2)
print(len(matches))

plt.imshow(img3),plt.show()
```

There is a third type of matching that is currently broken even in the latest version of OpenCV. Flann based matching. When that is fixed, I suggest you switch to that or just apply some smarts to the image.

For example, if you add gyros to the system, you can throw out matches outside of the window created by reducing your search window.

Comment: Yeah, that webcam is quite crappy. The matching with ORB-knnMatching looks pretty good,  How many matches did you get?

Comment: I use ORB because it is rotation and scale invariant.
I set it to 5000 matches and I got 2395 for the first set of code and around 3401 for the second. I disagree with the professor on using 0.75 for the second algorithm as it leaves too many bad matches.

I suggest using a standard algorithm to remove outliers based upon orientation difference even though they match in distance. Then use regions of similarity to track features.

Comment: By "second algorithm" I assume you mean Lowe's ratio, don't you? I'd say that if you lower it to 0.6 or even further the number of good matches increases dramatically.
In any case, you told me how many features ORB finds, I was asking how many good matches you get. In the picture it looks like no more than 200.

Comment: The algorithm is not Lowe's. It is a simple, not very scientific, filter. The ratio, since it is a number, should not be attributed to a person if it doesn't work in all cases or with a 95% confidence interval. 

You did not ask for "good" matches but maybe that is what you meant. The second picture has about 10% more good matches and it is around 200 without any tweaking. I use a specific AND scientific method to remove outliers. It works much better than the "second algorithm" and that other guy's ratio. Since that is tied to my work, I will not divulge that algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the feature you track you can it them rotation invariant and use correlation.